# Python collections.Counter How to print element and number of counts

Tags: python, count

```
with open ("words_count.txt", "a") as myfile:
count = Counter()
for word in words:
    count[word] += 1
#how to print word and tab seperated count here?
myfile.close()
```

So Im using counter library and I have no idea how to get every word with every count next to each other in file. I am aware, that if i write:

```
print(Counter(count).most_common(10))
```

I can get something like:

```
[('word1', 15529), ('word2', 14763), ...]....
```

But how do I actually print it to file? I have no idea how to call counter to get each word and each number of counts. Also most_common() gives complete list, still dont know how to call each value and number.

Link to library https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get tuple list you may do something like:

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    for word, count in word_list:
        f.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(word, count))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chaouche@karabeela ~/CODE/TEST/PYTHON $ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul  9 2012, 23:43:17)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import collections
>>> collections.C
collections.Callable(   collections.Container(  collections.Counter(
>>> help(collections.Counter)
```

Help says :

```
class Counter(__builtin__.dict)
 |  Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
 |  or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
 |  are stored as dictionary values.
```

> Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as
>   dictionary values

So I believe you could just do :

```
for word,occurences in count.iteritems():
    print "word %s is present %s times" %(word,occurences)
```

Not tested though, just guessing from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When there's a tuple list, I find it most convenient to write to a file( csv in this case ) by converting to a dictionary:

```
result = {}
for k,v in count.items():
    result[k] = v   
import csv
with open(output_file,'w',newline='') as writef:  
    w = csv.writer(writef)
    w.writerow(['word','word_count'])
    for key,value in result.items():
        w.writerow([key,value])
```

or even directly from Counter like so:

```
for key,value in collections.Counter(list).items():
        w.writerow([key,value])
```